# exclude specific strings of words using wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, macros, find-and-replace, wildcards

I cannot seem to come up with the appropriate wildcard (I suppose it must be `[!]`) which would exclude from the expression

`argument[oales]{1,4}`

the following three words

argument**os**
argument**a**
argument**as**

In other words, I would like it to find only the following three words

argument**o**
argument**al**
argument**ales**

so maybe it's the expression `argument[oales]{1,4}`  which is not appropriate to begin with.

Note that I am actually trying to find a 'pattern expression' so that I can use it with any other morphological word family; thus, those three words are mere examples.

I would use this pattern in a macro, and possibly in Find and Replace option, to implement replacements in batch.

Otherwise, would some add-in or third party 'search and replace' software tool do the job?

### **Update**

Here's the macro I'm using.

```
Sub ReplaceFromTableList()

Dim oChanges As Document, oDoc As Document
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oRng As Range
Dim rFindText As Range, rReplacement As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim sFname As String
Dim sAsk As String

    sFname = "C:\Users\Win7\Desktop\macro.docx" 'The table document
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oChanges = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFname, Visible:=False)
    Set oTable = oChanges.Tables(1)

    For i = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
        Set oRng = oDoc.Range
        Set rFindText = oTable.Cell(i, 1).Range
        rFindText.End = rFindText.End - 1
        Set rReplacement = oTable.Cell(i, 2).Range
        rReplacement.End = rReplacement.End - 1

        With oRng.Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            Do While .Execute(FindText:=rFindText, _
                  MatchCase:=True, _
                  MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                  MatchWildcards:=True, _
                  Forward:=True, _
                  Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True

            oRng.Select
            'oRng.FormattedText = rReplacement.FormattedText
            oRng.Text = rReplacement.Text
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Loop

        End With

    Next i

    oChanges.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges

lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

When debugging after Runtime Error 5692, the following section of the macro

```
Do While .Execute(FindText:=rFindText, _
                  MatchCase:=True, _
                  MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                  MatchWildcards:=True, _
                  Forward:=True, _
                  Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
```

appears in yellow, selected by Microsoft Word.

Comment: have you tried using that expression? What is your problem with it?

Comment: Please add only tags releavant to your question. Why do you have macros, microsoft-office?  Please add regex tag.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am actually trying to find a 'pattern expession' so that I can use it with any other morphological word family; thus, those three words are mere examples.

Comment: then please add more examples, it's not easy to understand what you're really asking.

Comment: @MátéJuhász put as simple as it gets, I'd like to know a wildcard expression to exclude specific strings of unicode characters in a specific order, so that adding such exression to the regex <ab[cdef]{1;4}>, I can avoid obtaining the strings abcde and abcdf, but I do get abc and abcdf.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately regex in Word doesn't support neither alternatives `|`, neither "zero or more" quantifiers (`*` or `{0,1}`), so I'm afraid there is no straightforward way to do that.

You need to look for each form in a separate search.

### Update

Re-reading your question I've realized you'll use it in a macro, fortunately there regular expressions are different, you can use:

`argument(o|al|ales)^`

Where `|` is separating optional parts and `^` is the end of the word (note the use of `()` instead of `[]`).

Comment: When executing the macro a message which pops up reads 'Runtime Error 5692'. Should I edit my original post adding the macro so that everybody can see?

Comment: do you get that error related to regular expression? If yes, then yes, please include code. If not, then ask it in a new question. Both cases describe at exactly which line do you get the error and what it is.

Comment: I've just updated my original post. After the error message, the debugging option highlights the part of the macro specified in the post. I am sorry for my possible bad formatting of the code lines.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd like to know some tool more powerful which enables more complex regex to edit text documents.